# read json zipped directly from urlrquest

Tags: python, json, api

I want to read a file directly to python w/o having to save it - the zip files are relatively small and definitely fit into mem.

I am currently trying this:

```
        import urllib
        import json
        access_url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.eia.gov/bulk/COAL.zip')
        data = json.loads(access_url.read().decode())
```

But I get the error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 15: invalid start byte

What extra step may solve this issue?

I am using python 3.6.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a zip file, what you want? See this `https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html`

Comment: What exactly does your COAL.zip contain?  Your problem is now that you are treating a zipped archive as json data, which is not right.  You need to extract the actual file containing json data from the archive. Do you know the name of the file inside your archive, for example? Does the archive contain many files?

Comment: @Hannu it contains a file called COAL.txt that's in json format.

Comment: @RaminNietzsche yes, but i'd want then to unzip and get the json w/o having to save it in disk since this are small files...

Answer (score 5):

You now treat a zipped archive (that can contain many files) as a file containing your actual data.  Let us assume your zip contains only one file that then contains the actual JSON data. This would work:

```
import zipfile
import io
import urllib
import json

access_url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.eia.gov/bulk/COAL.zip')

z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(access_url.read()))
data = json.loads(z.read(z.infolist()[0]).decode())
print(data)
```

Or something like that. I was not actually able to test on live data but give it a go. It basically unzips the first file it finds in your archive and then treats this as json.

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib.request
import json
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile


access_url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.eia.gov/bulk/COAL.zip')
zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(access_url.read()))
zdata = zf.read('COAL.txt')

print(zdata)
```